# Mass moving in parabola, Equation of motion?

Tags: conic-sections, classical-mechanics, cylindrical-coordinates

I just had a classical mechanics exam where there is a question asking about a movement of mass m moving in a parabola, where Z=(1/2)*a*(x^2+y^2). gravity acts as -mg^z

The first parts asks to express the motion in cylindrical coordinates and find its virtual displacement.
The second  part asks to find second derivative with generalized coordinates
Then by calculating virtual work done by inertia and by applied force and thus calculate the equation of motion with d'Alembert principle.

so for part 1 I wrote r(^r)=s(s^)+ z(^z) =s(^s)+(1/2)a(s^2)(^z), and then calculated the virtual displacement. 
For second part, I just copied the second derivative of 
r(^r) from formula sheet (I did not forget to put in z=(1/2)a(s^2)(^z))
However, as I proceed, I got some funny answers and did not reach to something that looks meaningful.

Can anyone help me write the virtual displacement and second derivative of r(^r) down?
Sorry if this looks really messy, I am new to this forum

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is there some connection between the variables $Z$ and $z$? What is the definition of the "virtual displacement"? How should the "expression of motion" look like? What do the words "gravity acts as $-mg^z$" mean? Is it the value of potential energy or some other concept?

Comment: I rolled back to the original question because the edited version was even less understandable. I presume John Liu by (^z) (and so on) means the unit vector along the $z$ axis: if so he should edit his question and substitute (^z) with $\hat z$, explaining what that means.